# How to save Python Dict Values to SQLite Model?

Tags: python, sqlite, dictionary

I am calling an API that returns JSON data.  I am using json.loads to decode the JSON to Python as a dictionary.  The dictionary that returns is a somewhat complex nested dictonary with nested lists as well.

For example:

```
{ "educations": { "_total": 1, "values": [{ "degree": "Bachelor of Arts", "fieldOfStudy": "Psychology", "schoolName": "Antioch University Seattle" }] }
```

How do I store each of the values into an SQLite database with the model defined as:

```
class Educations(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Candidate)
    degree = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    fieldOfStudy = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    schoolName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Each education is associated with a Candidate which is defined in the Candidate class (not shown here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the fields in new object like

```
# Get after json.dump
json_data = { "educations": { "_total": 1, "values": [{ "degree": "Bachelor of Arts", "fieldOfStudy": "Psychology", "schoolName": "Antioch University Seattle" }] }

for each_education in json_data['educations']['values']
    new_education = Education(**each_education)
    # Set the name foreign key
    # new_educaiton.name = name
    new_education.save()
```

*Note: How you will get the data for the `name` foreignkey is not mention in your question so that also you can set.*

Comment: I'm sorry - for my understanding is this what is going on? (1) get json_data using json.dump (2) define variable each_education to loop through every value under the "value" key under the "educations" key (#) (3) map new_education variable to save to the class Educations (4) save new_educations to database with new_education.save()  Is this logic correct?

Comment: yes try your code and if get error then past that error so we can solve that :)

Comment: Thanks Lafada - I think your answer works but the structure of the JSON that I am returning has more levels under [education] and [values] that I don't think the **each_education argument worked.  I had to individually call each value in the dictionary that i wanted and then saved it like you did.  I was able to get it to work though after you pointed me to the right direction! thank you.

Comment: That is up to you how you structure data.